# Troubleshooting rails 6, bootstrap 4, webpacker on heroku

Tags: heroku, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

Heroku deploy fails. So I tried doing it locally same issue.

```
$ NODE_ENV=production RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
yarn install v1.13.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.6.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
✨  Done in 7.99s.
** Execute assets:precompile
I, [2019-04-16T12:10:11.016887 #96897]  INFO -- : Writing /private/tmp/template-a32b218/public/assets/application-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css
I, [2019-04-16T12:10:11.017485 #96897]  INFO -- : Writing /private/tmp/template-a32b218/public/assets/application-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css.gz
** Invoke webpacker:compile (first_time)
** Invoke webpacker:verify_install (first_time)
** Invoke webpacker:check_node (first_time)
** Execute webpacker:check_node
** Invoke webpacker:check_yarn (first_time)
** Execute webpacker:check_yarn
** Invoke webpacker:check_binstubs (first_time)
** Execute webpacker:check_binstubs
** Execute webpacker:verify_install
** Invoke environment 
** Execute webpacker:compile
Compiling…
Compilation failed:

$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpacker can silently hang if you forgot to do a "yarn add " before actually using a package in your application.

Comment: they may have fixed it nowdadays

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question.

In `config/webpacker.yml`, there's a boolean option to make the output more verbose. And it told me there's was a typo in one of my include statements.

Comment: What setting did you use? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: I forget now but I think I discvered it in the official web packer documentation

Comment: @Cimm, set webpack_compile_output to true